# ERD diagram for all entities failing in Dynamics 365 - Error: Found an attribute with unrecognized required level

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

I am trying to generate **ERD** for all entities in our Dynamics 365 instance using *Microsoft Dynamics SDK Code* through *Visual Studios*, but getting the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]:
>   Found an attribute with unrecognised required level.  (Fault Detail is
>   equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

Part of the code where failing:

```
 // Load the metadata.
   Console.WriteLine("Loading Metadata...");
   RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest()
   {
         EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity | EntityFilters.Attributes | EntityFilters.Relationships,
         RetrieveAsIfPublished = true,

  };
  RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse response = null;
  try
  {

 Error Point>   response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(request);
                builder._metadataResponse = response;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
```

Please not that using `RetrieveEntityResponse` (for single entity) works, but does not show related entities in *MS Visio* diagram.

I have also used `MetadataDiagramConsole.exe` to run this for all entities, but it throws an *error* and `SDK` version is latest.

Thanks.

Comment: Works on my Online instance, you have something broken inside your CRM somewhere (no way to tell from the code / error, maybe try tracing)

Comment: If you're on-prem then query the Attribute table:

"select distinct AttributeRequiredLevelId from MetadataSchema.Attribute"

Expected values:
none, recommended, required, systemrequired.

Do you see something else?